# Civil War Pension Cards - "Date Of Filing" explanation

Tags: united-states, military-records, us-civil-war, pension-records

**Background**. While researching ancestor named Henry SCHRIML born 5 OCT 1809 Bavaria and died 16 APR 1865. Married to Katherine Maria HERRMANN born 24 JUL 1815  Germany and died 29 Jan 1901 Dayton, Ohio. I found family writings that "... [h]e had been an officer [Captain] in the Civil War, was shot in the chest by the enemy and contracted tuberculosis and died shortly afterwards". Because of surname misspellings, "Americanizing" (Schriml, Schimmel, Schiml, Smith, Schmidt, etc), I cannot find him nor the widow pension for his wife.

**Question** To make sure I'm not eliminating folks, I want to make sure I'm understanding the use of the "Date Of Filing" portion of the Civil War pension cards. So I'm looking for an explanation or definition of that column on the cards. Thank you.

Comment: Which series of Civil War Pension cards have you been looking at -- and if you're looking online, which sites have you used?  There is more than one series of pension index cards.  Did his widow remarry?

Comment: Also -- do you have any indication of what units he may have served with?

Comment: If your real question is, "Can I rule out any pensions that were filed for after Katherine Maria's death on 29 Jan 1901?" then the question should be edited to reflect that.